# Adding calculated field column to a pandas multi level column pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas pivot table in python like this

[image: My Pivot Table]

How can I add additional column of calculated field to this pivot table showing the % of increase/decrease of Breached_Amount?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though it's hard to tell without having data as text to copy-paste:

```
before = df.loc[:, ('Breached_Amount', '2019-01-10')] 
after = df.loc[:, ('Breached_Amount', '2019-01-11')] 
df.loc[:, ('Breached_Amount', 'pct_change')] = ((after - before) / before)
```