# Gspread to create a pivot table with index and columns on Google Sheets

Tags: python, gspread

I am running this code below,

```
sh = gc.open_by_url('..........')
worksheet = sh.worksheet('Sheet1')
worksheet.update([df2.columns.values.tolist()] + df2.values.tolist()+df2.index.values.tolist())
```

df2 is a multi-index pivot table and running this code writes only the values and columns but does not include the index on Google sheets. Is there a way to include the index and the ability to change the format of the header on Google sheets?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample values and the sample output situation you expect as the image?

Comment: Hi tanaike, thanks for the reply. The df2 or the pivot table looks like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163570/adding-calculated-field-column-to-a-pandas-multi-level-column-pivot-table

Comment: And when I run the code above, it does not write the index of the pivot table, but only the columns are being written on the google sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No Tanaiki, sorry for making it unclear. Normally, there are three parts in the pivot table, 1. index, 2. columns, 3. values. The code only writes the values and columns, but not index. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue and resolved this using a companion library [gspread_pandas](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gspread_pandas.html#module-gspread_pandas.spread)

## The issue:

MultiIndex (row or column) are not natively supported in the exchange between `gspread` and the google sheets API.

## The specific question:

> Is there a way to include the index and the ability to change the format of the header on Google sheets?

## A solution:

`gspread_pandas.Spread.dt_to_sheet()` method with the parameters to modify how MultiIndex rows and columns should be handled.  This includes a series of boolean flags for

- including/excluding the index, columns
- merging/not merging multindex rows and columns
- adding a freeze pane for header or indexes

## Solution applied to the code provided:

### Original Code

```
sh = gc.open_by_url('..........')
worksheet = sh.worksheet('Sheet1')
worksheet.update([df2.columns.values.tolist()] + df2.values.tolist()+df2.index.values.tolist())
```

### Modified Code

```
# Import the gspread_pandas 'Spread' module
from gspread_pandas import Spread

# Using the same credentials used for gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = Spread(spread='https://...spreadsheet_url...', creds=credentials)
sh.df_to_sheets(df=df2, # Your dataframe
                sheet='Sheet 1',  # Target sheet name
                start='A1', # First cell to place the data in
                index=True, # Show the index
                headers=True, # Show the columns
                merge_headers=True, # Merge the cells of multiindex headers
                merge_index=True, # Merge the rows of the muliindex index
                freeze_headers=True, # Freeze the header rows
               )
```